# How do I fix the 4 nodes ignored DFTB input file error in the attached input file?

Tags: dftb-plus, density-functional-tight-binding

I am trying to run MD using DFTB+ v 22.2, however, my input fails with the following errors:

```
WARNING!
-> The following 4 node(s) have been ignored by the parser:
(1)
Path: dftbplusinput/Hamiltonian/DFTB/KPointsAndWeights
Line: 37-42 (File: dftb_in.hsd)
(2)
Path: dftbplusinput/Hamiltonian/DFTB/Filling/Fermi/IndependentKFilling
Line: 63-63 (File: dftb_in.hsd)
(3)
Path: dftbplusinput/Hamiltonian/DFTB/EwaldParameter
Line: 86-86 (File: dftb_in.hsd)
(4)
Path: dftbplusinput/Hamiltonian/DFTB/EwaldTolerance
Line: 87-87 (File: dftb_in.hsd)

ERROR!
-> Code halting due to the presence of errors in dftb_in file.
```

However, there are no errors specified apart from the 4 mentioned above. I wonder if someone could take a look at the input file and advise. The text file is available at [here.](https://pastebin.com/CS46Hk5v)

I sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: You can try contacting Prof. Bálint Aradi via DFTB+ user forum. He would be able to guide you. Make sure to include your full input file with the email.

Comment: Did you ask this question anywhere else?